# How to separate username and email on separate pages ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

I am a developer starting out my career.

My task is to create an Authentication Server using ASP Identity and IdentityServer4.

My login page needs to be created across 2 different pages (Like with Microsoft). First the user will enter a username. I will verify the username to my DB or an Active Directory. After this confirmation the password will be required on the next page

I do not know how to implement this and I am struggling to find helpful online resources to help me solve my problem. I am looking for assistance on how to implement this and solve this problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I doubt you will find any exampel of this online and I think you need to develop this by your self

As a starting point, what you need to do is to modify **\Quickstart\Account\AccountController** controler class and its corresponding views.

As a comfort you only need to modify this class to accomplish what you are after.

Perhaps this [example](https://github.com/KevinDockx/ApiSecurityInDepth/blob/master/ApiSecurityInDepth.IDP/Quickstart/Account/AccountController.cs) might give you some guidance.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Would you maybe elaborate a bit more on how you think i should implement it? do i just separate the current (quickstart)login page, with it's models and then split up the controller for the username check and then the password. I have both ASP Identity and IdentityServer4 scaffolded pages. Are they both necessary?

Comment: I haven't used ASP.NET Identity, so I am not sure about that part. But in IdentityServer all it cares about is that you eventually create a valid user and call the await HttpContext.SignInAsync(isuser, props); method . What you do berfore that is all up to you. See the link in my question. Hope this is an acceptable answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't make this too difficult. With 2FA you append a step and in this case you take one step prior to login. Please note, I didn't test the code below, it's just to give you an idea.

Extend `LoginViewModel` with an indiciation of the current step, e.g. `StepNr`. This value is for building the view, you don't have to persist it in the form (as hidden field).

Keep the current login method but change the view (hide the password field based on this StepNr that is 2 or !2):

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(string returnUrl)
{
    var vm = await BuildLoginViewModelAsync(returnUrl);
    // ...
    return View(vm);
}
```

Copy the current Login method to e.g. LoginStep2 and split functionality:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string button)
{
    if (button != "login")
    {
        // ...
    }

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Username);

        model.StepNr = 2;

        // This will show the same view but now hide the username field based on StepNr
        // Do not forget to persist the username (hidden field).
        if (user != null)
            return View("login", model);

        ModelState.AddModelError(nameof(model.Username), "Invalid username");
    }

    // something went wrong, show form with error
    return View(model);
}
```

And add another method where you handle step2:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> LoginStep2(LoginViewModel model, string button)
{
    if (button != "login")
    {
        // ...
    }

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // If the name has been altered somehow and is now invalid then you can redirect to step 1
        var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Username);
        if (user == null)
        {
            model.StepNr = 1;
            ModelState.AddModelError(nameof(model.Username), "Invalid username");
            return View(model);
        }

        // The user is valid
        var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user, model.Password, 
                                                      model.RememberLogin, lockoutOnFailure: true);

        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            // perform actual login
            // ...
        }

        if (result.RequiresTwoFactor)
        {
            // select provider
            // ...
        }

        if (result.IsLockedOut)
        {
            // show locked out page
            // ...
        }
    }

    // something went wrong, show form with error
    return View(model);
}
```

In the Login View make sure to set the correct url for the next step. For `StepNr != 2` submit to *Login*, and for `StepNr == 2` submit to *LoginStep2*.